# how to reinstall SIGQUIT handler after SIGALRM is delivered - unix/c?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I'm trying to setup some signal handlers at the moment. Specifically, I want to install a SIGQUIT handler that reverts to default handling but then reinstalls the SIGQUIT handler after n seconds.

When I initially install my signal handlers in main() there is no issue, however when I add the code to try to reinstall my SIGQUIT handler in my SIGALRM handler I keep getting the following error message upon compilation:

```
ish.c: In function ‘SIGALRM_Handler’:
ish.c:42: error: ‘SIGQUIT_Handler’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ish.c:42: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ish.c:42: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Here are the relevant snippets of code. All I want to do is reinstall the SIGQUIT handler any time the alarm is triggered, but I am not sure how to proceed?

```
/* SIGALRM handler */

static void SIGALRM_Handler(int iSig)
{
   void (*pfRet)(int);
   /* reinstall SIGQUIT handler */
   pfRet = signal(SIGQUIT, SIGQUIT_Handler);
   if (pfRet == SIG_ERR) { perror("SIGQUIT_Handler"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* SIGQUIT handler */

static void SIGQUIT_Handler(int iSig)
{
   void (*pfRet)(int);
   /* Print message followed by shell prompt */
   printf("Type Ctrl-\\ again within 5 seconds to exit\n");
   printf("------------------------------------\n");
   printf("%c ", '%');
   fflush(NULL);
   /* install default SIGQUIT handling */
   pfRet = signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
   if (pfRet == SIG_ERR) { perror("SIGQUIT_Handler"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* set alarm for 5 seconds later */
   alarm(5);
}

...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *psFile;
   void (*pfRet)(int);
   sigset_t sSet;
   int iRet;
   assert(argv != NULL);
   /* make sure needed signals are not blocked */
   sigemptyset(&sSet);
   sigaddset(&sSet, SIGINT);
   sigaddset(&sSet, SIGQUIT);
   sigaddset(&sSet, SIGALRM);
   iRet = sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sSet, NULL);
   if (iRet == -1) { perror(argv[0]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* install SIGINT handler */
   pfRet = signal(SIGINT, SIGINT_Handler);
   if (pfRet == SIG_ERR) { perror(argv[0]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* install SIGALRM handler */
   pfRet = signal(SIGALRM, SIGALRM_Handler);
   if (pfRet == SIG_ERR) { perror(argv[0]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* install SIGQUIT handler */
   pfRet = signal(SIGQUIT, SIGQUIT_Handler);
   if (pfRet == SIG_ERR) { perror(argv[0]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* check for configuration file */
   if (argc > 2)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ish [configfile]\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (argc == 2)
   {
      psFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if (psFile != NULL)
      {
         handleProcess(psFile);
      }
      else
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "ish: ");
         perror(argv[1]);
      }
   }
   for(;;)
   {
      handleProcess(stdin);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Signals handlers shall only call async-signal-safe functions. Down under 2.4.2 on this page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03 there is a list of functions which (under POSIX compliant systems) are guaranteed to be this. `printf()` is **not** on this list.

Answer (score 2):

You need either to put the definition of `SIGQUIT_Handler()` before the reference to it in `SIGALRM_Handler()`, or to add a declaration before it:

```
static void SIGQUIT_Handler(int iSig);
```

Either will work, but one or the other is necessary.  Why?  When you write:

```
signal(SIGQUIT, SIGQUIT_Handler);
```

the second argument must be a pointer to a function, but the compiler must know that the name represents a pointer to a function because it has been declared before it is used.  As it stands, the name `SIGQUIT_Handler` has never been declared or defined, so the compiler does not know what it is.

Comment: oh silly me. been coding in rails all summer. lol. thanks Jonathan.